# What design pattern should I use for a simple reporting system

Tags: java, design-patterns, servlets, struts2

I'm working on a java application for a web based reporting system. The application currently uses struts2 for some reports and basic servlets for others. The code is all over the place and I want to put some sanity to the code.

The workflow from outside-in is as follows:

1. User Clicks on a link in navigation for a report
2. Report's search page (with 5 to 6 fields relating to the logged in user) comes up
3. user selects parameters
4. form gets submitted to Servlet/Struts2Controller

   - Servlet/Struts2Controller collects parameters, based on some logic, calls the DAO, fetches data, and forwards to next page
5. depending on the parameters the final report is displayed

From the above, point 2 is mostly same for all reports. So I've made a `GenericSearchClass` which has all the methods needed to show the initial search page for some report.

**My questions are:**

- what kind of pattern can I use when from the moment when form is submitted to when the final page is shown?
- Should I use a template method, with an abstract class and concrete classes that have their own implementation of the template method.
- If so, what should be my template method. Is there a better pattern for problems like these?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using a Model View Controller pattern in struts 
[Tutorial I found here from a google search http://www.vaannila.com/ ]

If you have long running reports I would suggest that you run the reports asynchronously using some AJAX on the front end to prevent users from requesting the same long running report multiple times. Reports that take more that half a minute to fill would fall in to this category.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i in position like you too.
i use hibernate, struts2 and jasper for report. report and charting design in IReport.
the query using native query in hibernate then just pass the list object to jasper using struts 2.

your steps 1-3 in jsp. 
your step 4 you create the DAO depend on query in hibernate (if must join you use native query). 
your step 5. get the object list(struts 2 action) and send to jasper using struts2(struts2 xml) design in ireport you just name the field same as property on object list your passing

or 
you just query in jasper and passing parameter(user input) and connection(jdbc)-> easy way
you can researh in detail about hibernate->struts2->ireport(jasper,jfreechart)